# Possible to perform forward declaration in R?

Tags: r, forward-declaration

Is it possible to perform forward declaration in R?
Or is it advisable to use separate files for functions instead?

I enjoy the aspect of having all functions listed in start of the script,
as well as being able to "play around" in a main-function as in C++, with the other functions defined after the main. Scrolling to the bottom of the program to work in the script/file does not make sense to me.

Comment: R doesn't care in which order you define functions as long as they are defined before you call them. However, best practice is to create a package if you have that many functions.

Comment: We can keep custom functions in a separate file, for example, in *myFunctions.R*, then call source like `source("myFunctions.R", local = TRUE)` in our *main.R* file.